# Dataflow AvroCoder seems to lose type information for Object serialization

Tags: avro, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a custom type which is passed along `PCollections` and is annotated with `@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)` - this type contains a few primitives along with a `Map<String, Object>` which is extracted from a JSON string using a reader.

When read initially, the type information from the JSON is maintained and hence, I am able to cast a value to `String` or any other type as applicable. But in later stages of the pipeline, when I cast the same value to `String`, I get an exception like `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String` - this probably means that the type information for each object in the `Map` has not been passed along in the pipeline. Is this a restriction of AvroCoder - if so, is there a work around or am I doing something wrong? The `Map` values will be of different types (read from a JSON), including `String`, `int`, `double` - hence I need to continue using an `Object` type.

To verify the coder's behavior, I built a sample program which mimics the behavior and will end up with the `ClassCastException` as explained above.

```
    String filename = "out.avro";
    AvroCoder<Object> coder = AvroCoder.of(TypeDescriptor.of(Object.class));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    coder.encode("test", oos, new Coder.Context(true));
    oos.close();
    fos.close();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    System.out.println((String) coder.decode(ois, new Coder.Context(true)));
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR `AvroCoder` can only be used with a concrete class.

`AvroCoder`, by nature, uses [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/), which is a schema-based serialization format, rather than a way to serialize arbitrary opaque Java objects.

`AvroCoder` uses the fields of the given class as the schema - these are the fields that will be serialized when encoding the data and deserializing when decoding it. You're specifying `Object.class`, which has no fields.

Likewise, the fields will be set on a new instance of the specified class. So in your case, deserialization creates a new `Object`, and since the `Object` class doesn't set any fields, deserialization doesn't attempt to set any fields on this `Object`, and you end up with a basic empty `Object` instance.

For serializing/deserializing arbitrary objects (though they have to implement `Serializable`), use `SerializableCoder`.

Comment: I pretty much did that except for implementing `Serializable`, I used a member variable to store the serialized `byte[]` which is ugly, given that we have `SerializableCoder`. Will update it - thanks!